# how to make left join using LINQ properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have 3 models (employee, division, and permission). I made LINQ join between them. Hover, no result displayed, Although the basic model "Admin" has data.

I made LINQ query to get all employees with role "Admin" with their permissions and belonging divisions.

LINQ join

```
        IList<Employee> Admins = await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin");
        // IList<Employee> Employees = await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Employee");
        // IList<Employee> Followers = await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Follower");
        List<Permission> permissions = _context.Permission.ToList();
        List<Division> divisions = _context.Division.ToList();

        ViewBag.GetAdmins = (from A in Admins
                     join P in permissions
                     on A.Id equals P.EmpID
                     from _p in permissions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join D in divisions
                     on A.DivID equals D.DivID
                     from _d in divisions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new VMEmployee { Admins = A, Permissions = _p, Divisions = _d }).ToList();
```

[Admins are not empty, although ViewBag.GetAdmins returns nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OupOf.png)

Do I have anything wrong with my LINQ?

--- Just in case you need to take a look at models

```
//employee
public class Employee : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }

    public override string Email { get => base.Email; set => base.Email = value; }

    public string HomePhone { get; set; }

    public string OfficePhone { get; set; }

    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    public int? DivID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DivID")]
    public Division division { get; set; }

}
//permission
public class Permission
{
    [Key]
    public int PerID { get; set; }
    public string PermissionsList { get; set; }

    public string BlockList { get; set; }
    public int DivID { get; set; }

    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public Employee employee { get; set; }

}
//division
public class Division 
{
    [Key]
    public int DivID { get; set; }
    public string DivName { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have try to output the generated SQL and test the query?

Comment: Can you show the method `GetUsersInRoleAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

the solution

```
        ViewBag.GetAdmins = (from A in Admins
                     join P in permissions
                     on A.Id equals P.EmpID into PP
                     from _p in PP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join D in divisions
                     on A.DivID equals D.DivID into DD
                     from _d in DD.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new VMEmployee { Admins = A, Permissions = _p, Divisions = _d }).ToList();
```